# Create feature branch for files already pushed to master branch for pull request

Tags: git, gitlab, branch

I have a master branch with following structure

```
master (branch)
folderA
folderB
folderC
```

I want to shift folderC to a feature branch so I can create a merge request to master branch.

It should be like this

```
master (branch)
folderA
folderB
```

```
newFeatureBranch1 
folderC
```

**I have pushed my code to an online repository what is the best way to do this?**

Comment: So the remote repository already has `folderC` for `master`?

Comment: yes basically I needed to push folderC from my local repo in a new branch but I pushed it in the master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From master:

```bash
git rm --cached folderC
git commit -m "Remove folderC"
git push origin master
```

then from the feature branch:

```bash
git add folderC
git commit -m "Add folderC"
git push origin featurebranch
```

Comment: Thanks for the help just had to put a -rf flag and it worked.